# Setting up a web server for access outside of subnetwork (Node.js, Nginx maybe, Ubuntu server)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, proxy, server

A little bit of context. I have developped a webapp on node.js (and a glamourous set of extensions). It has been approved for testing with true users at my company and i am supposed to deploy it now. Problem is that basically i have no idea unto how attack this problem. I have so many questions.

For the moment i have created a virtual machine on the local server. I have installed ubuntu server unto it and i have the intuition about how to deploy the app in this part (i suppose following the same steps as when i started to work on this project). I do not know however if i can have remote access from the outside of my network to this virtual machine. I also dont know if additional configuration in ubuntu's side is needed to make such an idea work (for example: in the installation there was a part about proxies that at the moment i decided to ignore)

From the few documents i have read about it since i was assigned this, a solution may lie in using nginx. The logic behind it if i am not mistaken (and please correct me if i am) is that nginx can help linking the HTTP requests (through the port 80 which is normally opened for access in most machines) and link it to a specific port on the machine (The sexy app i have developped).

In a more early stage, what ressources would i need to start this off? Would i need a domain name? IS it necessary? Do i need a different virtual server to link the apps or can they be on the same machine?

If you have additional comments or tips for someone that is learning to do this kind of thing, please do.

Comment: What you always can do is - if your server is reachable through a own ip address is to bind your node.js programm to a port and than call it via http://server-ip-address:nodejs-port. I tried to use paths to address ports but since now i was not able to do this with nginx

Answer (score 0):

For remote access, you will need a couple of things. First of all, you will need to make sure that your virtual machine is on a bridged adapter. I'm not sure what virtual machine you are on, or I'd give you more detail on how to do this. Second, you will need to make sure that your router has port 80 (or whatever port you chose to use) setup via port forwarding so that requests coming in map to the server (a request comes to the router on the port, the router must then know where to send those requests to). Finally, if you want to use a port other than port 80, you should be able to configure this in the nodejs configuration. This may also be configurable in the router so that requests coming in on port 80 are mapped to, say 8080, but, given that this is a company, it's probably easier to reconfigure the nodejs server than have it set up special mapping.

This experience comes from personal experience with hosting web servers at home. Corporate routers should need similar configuration unless each system has a public IP address on the internet, which is unlikely.